# Completely Remove Magento Template

Tags: magento

I installed magento on my webserver and tried 3 different templates on my URL. I want to stick on template number 3, but i don't know how te completely remove my 2 old templates.

There are still in my Admin Dashboard

How can i remove this old themes?

Greetings Dennis

Answer (score 0):

go to system=>configuration=>design and update theme name and default to your 3 theme and clear all you var/cache and see

Answer (score 0):

I will go with Anil's solution but even this doesn't help try deleting the theme file from the directory if you know what all you added to the project directory while adding those themes. Be careful do not delete any other files other than those theme files or regarding to it.

Clear your magento cache by going to cache management in system menu on admin panel.

I hope this will solve your issue.